# is cgroups limits per user or shared across all members?

Tags: linux, limit, cgroups

for example,

```
group memlimit {
    memory {
        #approx 200MB
        memory.limit_in_bytes = 200000000;
    }
}
```

will all members of memlimit share 200 MB, or will each member individually get 200 MB?